# How to store user profile information in firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an activity to store user's information in firebase database. This is the code which I have tried, but it is not storing any value in the database and the signout button is not working...

activity_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="www.edukeen.in.eduaspire.Home">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Personal details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="DOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editDOB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:ems="10"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editphone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="City"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editcity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Academic details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Class/year"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editclass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Board/Graduation degree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editboard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="School/college"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editschool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Hobbies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edithobbies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Achievements"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editachievements"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonsignout"
            android:text="Sign out"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Profile.java

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button signOut;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

private Button buttonSave;

private Firebase mref;

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editDOB;
private EditText editphone;
private EditText editcity;
private EditText editclass;
private EditText editboard;
private EditText editschool;
private EditText edithobbies;
private EditText editachievements;

FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

static final String TAG = "YOUR-TAG-NAME";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDOB);
    editphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editphone);
    editcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcity);
    editclass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editclass);
    editboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editboard);
    editschool = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editschool);
    edithobbies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edithobbies);
    editachievements = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editachievements);

    mref = new Firebase("https://*************.firebaseio.com/Users");

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };

    FirebaseUser userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (userID != null) {
        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){

                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref1 = mref.child("Name");
                Childref1.setValue(name);

                String DOB = editDOB.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref2 = mref.child("DOB");
                Childref2.setValue(DOB);

                String Phone = editphone.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref3 = mref.child("Phone");
                Childref3.setValue(Phone);

                String City = editcity.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref4 = mref.child("City");
                Childref4.setValue(City);

                String Class = editclass.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref5 = mref.child("Class");
                Childref5.setValue(Class);

                String Board = editboard.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref6 = mref.child("Bord");
                Childref6.setValue(Board);

                String School = editschool.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref7 = mref.child("School");
                Childref7.setValue(School);

                String Hobbies = edithobbies.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref8 = mref.child("Hobbies");
                Childref8.setValue(Hobbies);

                String Achievements = editachievements.getText().toString();
                Firebase Childref = mref.child("Achievements");
                Childref.setValue(Achievements);
            }
        });
    }

    //for signout start
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (userID == null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
}

public void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
}
```

Screen

[image: Profile screen]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

once user model gets filled by the profile details (feilds)

```
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

myRef = database.getReference("parent_node**strong text**name").child(user_profile_id);

myRef.child(user_profile_id).push();

childUpdates.put(user_profile_id, usermodel);

myRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

The above code generates parent node with user id and  the user model gets saved as a value for that id(i.e user id) , you may later fetch those profile details by calling userid as a key in the Firebase Database

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Where does one include this? In the onStateChanged method?

Comment: Firstly get the firebase instance along with child and add listener (addListenerForSingleValueEvent) on that , you will get overridden method named as on Datachange and post data to firebase inside it.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/PostDetailActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="RegisterUserActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rect01"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
            android:text="Register User"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gpsBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gps_white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconIv"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle01"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_key_white" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/iconIv"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">


            <com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileIv"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_person_gray"
                app:c_border="true"
                app:c_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:c_border_width="2dp" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/profileIv"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Full Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/nameEt"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addressLl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/phoneEt"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/countryEt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_gray"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                    android:hint="Country"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/stateEt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_gray"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                    android:hint="State"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/cityEt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_gray"
                    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                    android:hint="City"
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/addressEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressLl"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Complete Address"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressEt"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mail_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/emailEt"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cPasswordEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/passwordEt"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect02"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_gray"
                android:drawablePadding="15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cPasswordEt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
                android:minWidth="120dp"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registerSellerTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_medium"
        android:text="@string/registerSeller"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Place all the values you want in a hashMap and save all of them together by using the setValue function.

Also, if there is by chance a small problem with your mref, try declaring it like this.

```
mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

I hope this helps